# Most efficient way to translate C++ classes/objects into Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp

I am new to Rccp and came across a problem by translating C++ code into the Rcpp environment – and I could not find a solution so far (this is an edited version of my original post that I think was unclear):

Background: I have multiple parameters and large matrices/arrays that needs to be transferred to the C++ level. In C++, I have several functions that need to access these parameters and matrices and in some cases, change values etc. In C++ I would create classes that combine all parameters and matrices as well as the functions that need to access them. By doing so, I dod not need to pass them (each time) to the function.

Issue: I could not figure out how that may work with Rcpp. In the example below (the function is stupid, but hopefully an easy way to illustrate my issue), I create a matrix in R that is then used in C++. However, I then hand the entire matrix over to a sub-function in order to use the matrix within this function. This seems a very bad idea and I would rater like to have the matrix M in the namespace memory and access it in the sub function without cloning it.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;


double fnc1 (int t, int s, arma::mat M) // I would prefer not to have M in the arguments but rather available in the namespace
{
 double out = M(t,s) - M(t,s);
 return out;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Rout (arma::mat M)
{
 int ncol = M.n_cols;
 int nrow = M.n_rows;

 for(int c = 0; c<ncol; ++c)
 {
  for(int r = 0; r<nrow; ++r)
  {
   M(r,c) =  fnc1(r, c, M);
  }
 }

return M;
}


/*** R
m <- matrix(runif(50), ncol = 10, nrow = 5)
Rout(m)
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's talk about *R* to *C++*. At somepoint, you have to have a function *exported* to *R* that will receive an *R* object and *pass* it back to *C++*. Once inside *C++*, the sky's the limit as to how you want to structure the interaction with that object. The thought process of:

> However, I then hand the entire matrix over to a sub-function in order to use the matrix within this function. This seems a very bad idea and **I would rater like to have the matrix M in the namespace memory and *access it in the sub function without cloning it***.

is slightly problematic as you have now just introduced a *global variable* called *M* to handle your data. If *M* is not initialized, then the routine will falter. If you inadvertently modify *M*, then the data will *change* for all routines. So, I'm not sure going the global variable approach is the solution you desire.

The main issue you seem to have is the emphasized portion regarding a "clone". When working with *C++*, the default pass by construct is to *copy* the object. However, unlike *R*, it is very easy to *pass by reference* by prefixing object names with `&` and, thus, negate a copy entirely. This localizes the process.

#### Pass-by-Reference Demo

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;


double fnc1 (int t, int s, const arma::mat& M) {
  double out = M(t,s) - M(t,s);
  return out;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Rout (arma::mat& M) {
  int ncol = M.n_cols;
  int nrow = M.n_rows;

  for(int c = 0; c<ncol; ++c) {
    for(int r = 0; r<nrow; ++r) {
      M(r,c) =  fnc1(r, c, M);
    }
  }

  return M;
}


/*** R
m <- matrix(runif(50), ncol = 10, nrow = 5)
Rout(m)
*/
```

#### Global Variable Demo

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// Create a namespace to store M
namespace toad {
 arma::mat M;
}

double fnc1 (int t, int s) 
{
  double out = toad::M(t,s) - toad::M(t,s);
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void Rin (arma::mat M)
{
 toad::M = M;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void Rmanipulate()
{
  int ncol = toad::M.n_cols;
  int nrow = toad::M.n_rows;

  for(int c = 0; c<ncol; ++c)
  {
    for(int r = 0; r<nrow; ++r)
    {
      toad::M(r,c) =  fnc1(r, c);
    }
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Rout (){
  return toad::M;
}


/*** R
m <- matrix(runif(50), ncol = 10, nrow = 5)
Rin(m)
Rmanipulate()
Rout()
*/
```

Comment: Fantastic! The pass-by-reference approach is exactly what I was looking for (also good to know the global option). Thanks for your elaborate and very helpful response!